# Canvas Engine : draw an isometric map

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using http://canvasengine.net/ for a webgame.

I'm trying to generate an isometric map from a JSON file that I created with the software http://www.mapeditor.org/.

The engine and software are compatibles.

So, i have a json file like :

```
  { "height":5,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         "height":5,
         "name":"Calque de Tile 1",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":5,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "orientation":"isometric",
 "properties":
    {

    },
 "tileheight":41,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"..\/..\/..\/wamp\/www\/Symfony\/src\/Dontdie\/MapBundle\/Resources\/public\/images\/herbe.png",
         "imageheight":41,
         "imagewidth":82,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"herbe",
         "properties":
            {

            },
         "spacing":0,
         "tileheight":41,
         "tilewidth":82
        }],
 "tilewidth":82,
 "version":1,
 "width":5
}
```

After, i include this file in Js with canvasengine :

```
var url = "{{ asset('bundles/dontdiemap_temp/images/map.json') }}";
    var canvas = CE.defines("canvas_id").
        extend(Tiled).
        ready(function() {
            canvas.Scene.call("MyScene");
        });

    canvas.Scene.new({
        name: "MyScene",
        materials: {
            images: {
                herbe: "{{ asset('bundles/dontdiemap_temp/images/herbe.png') }}"
            }
        },
        ready: function(stage) {
             var el = this.createElement();
             var tiled = canvas.Tiled.new();
            tiled.load(this, el, url);
            tiled.ready(function() {
                 var tile_w = this.getTileWidth(),
                     tile_h = this.getTileHeight(),
                     layer_object = this.getLayerObject();
                 stage.append(el);
            });

        }
    });
```

And now, i have a problem. Lokk as this screen :

[image: Screen off my map]

Tiles do not stack as it should, in isometric but just like a 2d normal map.

Have you any ideas ?? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: https://github.com/RSamaium/CanvasEngine/issues/14
The Tiled.js extention does not support isometric maps. You'll have to do translation from scratch :(